# Angularjs How to make two inputs in-line on click checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make two inputs inline after clicking the checkbox, so if the Inline checkbox is clicked, those two inputs will sit in one line. Any ideas?

Before click "Inline" checkbox:

Question Inline
Enter text...

After click "Inline" checkbox:
Question Enter text... Inline

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>Angular - My Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <h1>My Notes</h1>
      <div class="note-section">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Question">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="inline"> Inline <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter text...">
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put an `ng-hide` on the br like this:

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Question">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="inline" ng-model="inlineChecked"> Inline 
    <br ng-hide="inlineChecked">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter text...">    
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robianmcd/CMXcc/

Another solution would be to do this with a css class:

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Question">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="inline" ng-model="inlineChecked"> Inline 
    <input ng-class="{'blockInput': !inlineChecked}" type="text" placeholder="enter text...">    
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robianmcd/gPy45/

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you guide me how to input the "enter text" input in front of the "inline" checkbox?

Comment: @user3112938 what do you mean by in front of? The "enter text" input is already to the right of the inline checkbox when it is not checked.

Comment: what I mean is when the inline check box clicked, the "enter text" box goes to the left of the "Inline" checkbox

Comment: Ah so you just want it to move down but not to the left? You'd have to do some fancy CSS and I'm not great with CSS so don't think I can help you there. Sorry.

Comment: no, But I have updated the post, it explain more in detail, pls help~

Comment: -1 Sorry to be harsh, but @rob is not here to do your work or homework for you. You need to work through some of these problems yourself. Angular is a well documented framework with the tricky items, the least of which you've touched on in your questions. Do some research.

Comment: @user3112938 Ah I see. Still not sure how you would switch the order of those elements. Maybe you could do this with the Bootstraps pull-right class or something. I guess you could always just create two inline check boxes and only show one at a time but it's a bit of a hack. e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/robianmcd/pMtKR/